# how to filled the data in django templates

Tags: python, django

I want to `email` a template in django. The template has one variable say `name`. I want to filled this value. How to do that. context is not working because i don't need to render the page.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to render the template - and you do that via the context. How is it not working?

Comment: then how to fill the template variables

Answer (score 0):

> context is not working because i don't need to render the page.

I guess what you are looking for is [render_to_string](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
text = render_to_string('my_template.html', { 'name': 'xxx' })
```